# jQuery button position index

Tags: jquery

I have a a list of buttons within a class container.

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <button id="ONE">ONE</button>
    <button id="TWO">TWO</button>
    <button id="THREE">THREE</button>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to get is the numeric position of the button that I clicked:

```
$('.buttonContainer button').click(function (e) {
    var id = this.id;

    // id contains the name of the id of the button clicked.

});
```

I've tried:
    $('.buttonContainer button.clicked').index();

But that's not working.  Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```